# Informix Error Creating Function : SQL error(-999) Not implemented yet

Tags: sql, database, informix

I'm getting the **SQL Error(-999) Not implemented yet** in the below query inside a function:

```
 SELECT 
     RES.resourcename,
     RES.resourceloginid,
     RES.extension,
     ASD.eventdatetime,
     ASD.eventtype,
     RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY RES.resourcename ORDER BY RES.resourcename,ASD.eventdatetime)
FROM agentstatedetail ASD JOIN resource RES ON ASD.agentid=RES.resourceid
WHERE ASD.eventdatetime BETWEEN to_date('18/04/2015 00:00:00', 
            "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
     AND to_date('18/04/2015 23:59:59', "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
     AND ASD.agentid IN(2620,2622)
     AND ASD.eventtype IN(1, 7);
```

When I replace the rank statement with an interger it works properly. Also when I execute the query with rank function as a separate query (Not inside the function), I'm getting the desired results. Have any idea why I'm getting this error on having this query inside the function ?
Thanks alot...
Note: I'm using Server Studio as client

Comment: Well, the error clearly states, that using RANK in a function is not implemented yet.

Comment: @dnoeth: Thanks for the response. Is ther any other work around to calculate difference between consecutive event date time ? it would help me

Comment: I don't know about Informix, but if RANK is not supported this is probably the same for any other Windowed Aggregate Function. And old-sytel SQL for getting those results is horribly inefficient. So simply forget about doing this in a function.

Comment: Which version of Informix are you using? The OLAP functionality (such as RANK) was recently added, in 12.10 and maybe later versions of 11.70. If your version is older than that, it won't work and you'll need to upgrade. If your version supports it, then you should probably contact IBM/Informix Tech Support to find out whether it's a known problem and/or fixed in a more recent fix-pack. And, if it isn't a known problem, your report may help them. You should check the IDS 12.10 [Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.welcome.doc/welcome.htm) too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The Informix version was lower that 11.70 as you stated. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comment to answer.*</sup>

Which version of Informix are you using?

The OLAP functionality (such as RANK) was recently added, in 12.10 and maybe later versions of 11.70. If your version is older than that, it won't work and you'll need to upgrade.

If your version supports it, then you should probably contact IBM/Informix Tech Support to find out whether it's a known problem and/or fixed in a more recent fix-pack. And, if it isn't a known problem, your report may help them.

You should check the [IDS 12.10 Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.welcome.doc/welcome.htm) too.

---

And a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1707800/bharath) from [Bharath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1707800/bharath) confirms the 'version too old' hypothesis:

> The Informix version was lower that 11.70 as you stated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm responding for reference of future visitors as the specific issue is not correctly identified in previous comments and response.

You get that specific error code in Informix whenever your sub-query references an outer query column in its `WHEN` clause. In this particular instance is the `ASD.eventdatetime` reference which is triggering this error. Nothing to do with ranking.

Depending on circumstances you might work around this by using a `JOIN` instead. `ON` clauses do not show this restriction.

That is not to say that another, different, error would not be triggered by `RANK` in an older Informix release once that column reference is removed.

BTW, I happen to often fight with that awful database Cisco bestows upon us with CUCCX. Using `to_date` is gonna kill performance.